# Android emulator shows "Device Nexus_5_Edited_API_23 [emulator-5554] is online, waiting for processes to start up.."

Tags: android, android-emulator, emulation, android-virtual-device

Im trying to run a Hello Woeld app and my emulator won't run the application. I tried all the options like enabling/disabling Host GPU and lowering the resolution of the emulator etc., but not luck yet. The emulator will launch but will just show a black screen and the Run console in Android Studio will keep showing "Device Nexus_5_Edited_API_23 [emulator-5554] is online, waiting for processes to start up.." indefinitely.

My target version is API 23 and my emulator uses API 23 as well. Can someone please help me fix this issue?

Comment: I installed HAXM from https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager yet I get the emulator is online, waiting for processes to start up message forever. The app will never launch on my virtual device. Can someone please help? This is driving me crazy.

Comment: same [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33527421/emulator-cannot-start-up)

Answer (score 1):

It may be caused by your Emulator max RAM size.
API 23 needs more than 1GB to run, as explained here :
[emulator cannot start up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33527421/emulator-cannot-start-up)

Then dont forget to set HAXM max RAM size