# emulator cannot start up

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, android-service

I'm just install HAXM installer and Android SDK Tools and finally my AVD can launch. But the problem is it stucks on the android. I've been waiting for 20 minutes but it still not yet start up..

> emulator: device fd:664 HAXM is working and emulator runs in fast virt
>   mode creating window 61 83 462 820 emulator: UpdateCheck: current
>   version '24.4.1', last version '24.4.1'
>
> Device Nexus_5_API_23_x86 [emulator-5554] is online, waiting for
>   processes to start up.. Device Nexus_5_API_23_x86 [emulator-5554] is
>   online, waiting for processes to start up.. Device Nexus_5_API_23_x86
>   [emulator-5554] is online, waiting for processes to start up.. Device
>   connected: emulator-5554 Device connected: emulator-5554

[image]

Is it normal? How long it needs for set up? Have I missed install anything? Thanks

Comment: is it mac or windows ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Increase the memory on your emulator.
1.In android studio go to Tools--->AVD Manager
2. then click the edit button (green crayon) and click on "show advanced settings".

[image]

Comment: where can I find the setting?

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to [j2emanue](https://stackoverflow.com/users/835883/j2emanue)'s answer, if you're using command line to start the emulator, you can specify the `-memory` option. From the `emulator -help` command:

`-memory <size>  :  physical RAM size in MBs`

So you can:

`emulator -avd <avd_name> -memory 1024`