# USB device exceeds power limits

Tags: android, android-emulator, usb

OK, the `android studio` really drive me crazy.

At first, AVD cannot launch and I have post my issue here to [AVD not running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33417842/avd-not-running) and failed to create new virtual device [Throwable: Failed to create the SD card](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33419733/throwable-failed-to-create-the-sd-card)

After install Android SDK Tool from sdk manager and HAXM installer, it finally can lunch but [emulator cannot start up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33527421/emulator-cannot-start-up).

After I increase the emulator memory, my emulator works fine but I cannot use real device to run my project.

> Error: Power Surge On Hub Port: A USB device has exceeded the power
>   limits of its hub port

I'm not sure whether the error exists is due to the emulator setting because it can run before  the emulator memory get increased. Anyone can help? It totally frustrating.

Comment: This is just [a hardware configuration problem on Windows](https://www.google.co.jp/search?q=Error%3A+Power+Surge+On+Hub+Port%3A+A+USB+device+has+exceeded+the+power+limits+of+its+hub+port). Android Studio is not involved in this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try restart your system. I faced the same issue before, but it solved after I restart my system.

Answer (score 0):

This happened because I select `TB` in emulator setting. After change to `MB` and restart the system again, it solved

Comment: No, this did not solve the title problem of this question.  The emulator configuration has nothing to do with the USB electrical fault, because the emulator has nothing to do with USB.  Your question is off-topic for this site anyway, as it is a computer usage question rather than a software development one.

Comment: Ya, you are right. Now I get the same error again @@